# Xna NullReferenceException was unhandled (Object reference not set to instance error)

Tags: c#, object, xna, nullreferenceexception

I'm currently working on a project on XNA. My problem is that I'm trying to load  sprite font to the screen (By loading it in the Game1 Class), then proceeding to pass it on to another class in a draw method, to further draw it to the screen, except I get the proceeding error.

I've tried looking throughout my code, and realized that the sprite font is indeed initialized, as it is loaded. As well I used if statements previously to check if the object is null and to my understanding, it isn't, so what could be the issue? Here is a tid bit of my classes. Any help would certainly be appreciated. Also sorry for the long code, I felt it was needed to most a large amount of it to truly understand the problem.

Tid bit of Game1 Class

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    #region loadTextures
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    backGround = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MainMenu");
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth; // width of screen..
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight; //height of screen..

    IsMouseVisible = true;
    graphics.ApplyChanges(); // load images...

    HealthBar = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar");
    btnPlay = new cButton(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Button1"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    movement = new Movement(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpritesRe"), new Vector2(rndXpos, rndYpos), 64, 57, HealthBar, cBar,Content.Load<Texture2D>("Grave"));
    npc_creation = new NPC_Creation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("MonsterSprite"), screenRectangle,HealthBar,Content.Load<Texture2D>("Grave"));
    btnPlay.setPosition(new Vector2(350, 300));
    spritefont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("OnscreenLevel");

    StartGame();
    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
/// all content.
/// </summary>
protected override void UnloadContent()
{
    // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        this.Exit();

    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case GameState.MainMenu: // if mouse is clicked... call method
            if (btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
            btnPlay.Update(mouse);
            break;

        case GameState.Playing: // if true.. load new image...
            backGround = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Game Map");
            break;
    }


    //checks if character takes damage from being in range of enemy
    npc_creation.charWithinDamageRange(movement.getCharLocation());
    //checks if character is within sight range
    npc_creation.charWithinRange(movement.getCharLocation());
    //calls on monster update method, with the inputs:
    npc_creation.Update(gameTime, npc_creation.withinRangeOrNot(), movement.getCharLocation());

    //checks if monster is in range of character attack
    npc_creation.monsterTakeDamageRange(movement.getAttackRadius());

    npc_creation.charWithinDamageRange(movement.getCharLocation());

    if (npc_creation.withinDamageRangeOrNot() == true)
    {
        movement.decreaseCharHealth();
        npc_creation.charWithinDamageRange(movement.getCharLocation());
        npc_creation.withinDamageRangeOrNot();
    }

    while (npc_creation.inAttackRadius() == true)
    {
        npc_creation.decreaseMobHealth();
        movement.resetAttackRadius();
        npc_creation.monsterTakeDamageRange(movement.getAttackRadius());
        npc_creation.inAttackRadius();
    }
    movement.Update(gameTime);
    base.Update(gameTime);
}

/// <summary>
/// This is called when the game should draw itself.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    //Draw Any Scene Stuff Here

    spriteBatch.Draw(backGround, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

    switch (CurrentGameState)
    {
        case GameState.MainMenu: // if on main menu... draw button...
            btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
           // chardev.Draw(spriteBatch,spritefont);
            break;

        case GameState.Playing: // otherwise.. draw the character sprites
            movement.Draw(spriteBatch);
        npc_creation.Draw(spriteBatch, Color.White);
        chardev.Draw(spriteBatch, spritefont);//THIS IS WHERE THE SPRITEFONT IS PASSED TO THE DRAW METHOD!!!
            break;  
    }

    spriteBatch.End();
    // TODO: Add your drawing code here
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Character Development class (Where the draw method is)

```
class charDevelopment
{
    #region initalize


    int EXP = 50; // starting exp.. must be level 1...
    int LEVEL = 1;
    int SP = 10; // starting skill points
    int y;

    #endregion 

    public charDevelopment(int EXP)
    { // set value
        this.EXP = EXP;
        calcEXP(EXP);
    }

    public void calcEXP(int EXP)
    { // formula to calculate exp... arithmetic sequence... (150,300,600,1200,2400 etc..)
        y = 25 * EXP * (1 + EXP);
        checkLevel(y);
    }

    public int getEXP
    {
        get {return getEXP;}
        set {getEXP = EXP;}
    }
    #region levelCheck

    public void checkLevel(int y) 
    {
        // increment hp each level up (Can't spend skill points on it)
        if (y < 50)
        {
            LEVEL = 1;
            SP = 10;
        } // NEED A MORE EFFICIENT WAY TO DO THIS... possible for loop? ideas
        else if (y >= 50 && y < 150)
        {
            LEVEL = 1; SP += 10;
        }
        else if (y >= 150 && y < 300)
        {
            LEVEL = 2; SP += 10;
        }
        else if (y >= 300 && y < 600)
        {
            LEVEL = 3; SP += 10;
        }
        else if (y >= 600 && y < 1200)
        {
            LEVEL = 4; SP += 15;
        }
        else if (y >= 1200 && y < 2400)
        {
            LEVEL = 5; SP += 15;
        }
        else if (y >= 2400 && y < 4800)
        {
            LEVEL = 6; SP += 15;
        }
        else if (EXP >= 4800 && EXP < 9600)
        {
            LEVEL = 7; SP += 20;
        }
        else if (y >= 9600 && y < 19200)
        {
            LEVEL = 8; SP += 20;
        }
        else if (y >= 19200 && y < 38400)
        {
            LEVEL = 9; SP += 20;
        }
        else if (y >= 38400 && y < 76800)
        {
            LEVEL = 10; SP += 20;
        }
    }
    #endregion 

    public void checkSP ()
    {
        if(SP >0)
        {
            // display screen to chose skills which should be enhanced...
        }

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch, SpriteFont spritefont)
    {
        spritebatch.DrawString(spritefont, "Level: " , new Vector2(5, 0), Color.White);
    }

}
```

And the draw method in  another class.. which checks if the enemy monsters is dead... the user gains exp... passes it on to the class

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch, Color color)
{ // draw the texture
    if (Alive == true)
    {
        spritebatch.Draw(texture, pos, color);
        spritebatch.Draw(HealthBar, new Rectangle((int)pos.X - 2, (int)pos.Y - 8, (int)(HealthBar.Width * ((double)CurrentHealth / 100)), 5), Color.Red);
    }

    else if (Alive == false) // if the monster is dead... i.e health is 0....
    {// draw the grave... need a timer here...
        spritebatch.Draw(Grave, pos, color);
        speedXnpc = 0;
        speedYnpc = 0;
        monsterSpeed = 0;
        tempEXP += 25;
        chardev = new charDevelopment(tempEXP);// this line PASSES THE EXP
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please set a breakpoint on the line

"chardev.Draw(spriteBatch, spritefont);"

and verify that spriteFont is not "null"?

If you don't know what a breakpoint is: right-click on the code line and click on "Breakpoint > Insert Breakpoint". If you then start the game, it stops in this line and shows you the variables in a window called "Locals". Click on the plus-symbol near "this" in the window and check the "spriteFont"-value. I hope it was clear.

Comment: Yeah to my surprise it does state it is null. the chardev is null, the spritebatch and spritefont isn't.